# cookie is not being set

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

I'm using express session to generate my sessions and my cookies are being set in postman but they aren't showing up in the applications tab of chrome's dev tools.

this is my cookie config, secure is set to false for development

```
  name: "config",
  secret: sessionSecret,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60,
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: false
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
};
```

this is how I've ordered my global middleware

```
server.use(express.json());
server.use(session(sessionConfig));
server.use(cors());
server.use(morgan("combined"));
server.use("/api", Router);
```

the useEffect on my react App.js and the function it calls

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getAuthenticationStatus().then(() =>
      authenticated ? null : history.push("/")
    );
  }, []);

  const getAuthenticationStatus = async () => {
    await authenticateSession();
  };
```

the function being called by the function inside the useEffect

```
export const authenticateSession = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: AUTHENTICATION_IN_PROGRESS
  });
  return axios
    .get(`${endpoint}/api/auth/authenticate`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch({
        type: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error: ", error);
      dispatch({
        type: AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE
      });
    });
};
```

I'm at a loss as to why my cookie isn't being set

Comment: I have experienced similar with Spring. Here are some hints, because I am not familiar with technologies you are using. Chrome have a pretty strict policies to session cookies. If Chrome detects cookie with predefined name of session cookies (JSSESSIONID in case of Spring, maybe different in your case) it forces some limitations. One of these is, that session cookie must have `secure` flag true. I have hacked it by configuring Spring to use different name for session cookies,  eg `JSESSIONID_FOR_DEVELOPMENT`. Maybe it is possible do something similar with your server.

Comment: Also check if there is any warning in javascript console, but in my version of Chrome was logged no warning and cookie was simply thrown away without notice. You can also start your chrome with flag `--disable-web-security`, if it is only for development purposes